# Having Trouble with img-circle Rounded Images in Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3.0. I want to display three images with the class "img-circle". How do I get rid of the bullet points and the box surrounding these images?

Thanks

```
<div class="row">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="col-md-4">
                    <article class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="img/content writing.jpg" alt="pencil" class="img-circle">
                    <h3>Content Writing</h3>
                    <p>lore ipsum</p>
                </article>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-4">
                <article class="thumbnail">
                <img src="img/design.jpg" alt="folder" class="img-circle">
                <h3>Design</h3>
                <p>lore ipsum</p>
                </article>
             </li>
            <li class="col-md-4">
                <article class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="img/social media.jpg" alt="person" class="img-circle">
                    <h3>Social Media</h3>
                    <p>lore ipsum</p>
                </article>
            </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootstrap 3, thumbnails no longer need to be contained in a ul.thumbnails. Compare the [example code in the Bootstrap 2.3 documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#thumbnails) to that in [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails) (excerpted below):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/100%x180" alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Removing the ul will get rid of the bullet points.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `list-inline` to get rid of the bullets...

```
<div class="row">
    <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="col-md-4">
                    <article class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" alt="pencil" class="img-circle">
                    <h3>Content Writing</h3>
                    <p>lore ipsum</p>
                </article>
            </li>
              ...
```

Demo <kbd>**http://bootply.com/86476**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can also set your css to remove bullets from your ul like this:

```
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}
```